# How do I let the links of the OpenLayers attributions open up in a new tab?

Tags: openlayers, api, attribution

Our webserver has set X-Frame-Options to 'sameorigin'. So if I want to open the attribution links in an OpenStreetMap, the requests get blocked. So I want to let the links be opened in a new tab. How do I change the target-property of the a-elements to '_blank' while still using the OpenLayers API? 
I want do change it with the OpenLayers API and not "from outside" with JQuery etc.
enter image description here

[image: notices of errors etc]

Answer (score 1):

You can set attribution of source as `[]`, then only `openlayers.org` link will be left.

```
source: new ol.source.OSM({
  attributions: [],
  ...
```

or you can remove the whole attribution by setting `attributionOptions` option with `className: ""`

```
controls: ol.control.defaults({
  attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
    collapsible: false,
    className: ""
  })
}),
```

---

to set `target="_blank"`, customize `attribution` like:

```
attributions: [
  'All maps © <a href="http://www.openseamap.org/" target="_blank">OpenSeaMap</a>',
  ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION
],
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be to disable the X frame error, I had the same issue and the link below helped me solve this;

https://helpx.adobe.com/target/kb/how-to-use-a-browser-extension-to-remove-x-frame-options-console.html